# Prove that function $f$ is injective if its Jacobian matrix is positive definite.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, derivatives

Assume that $\Omega\in\mathbb{R}^m$ is an open convex set and the vector-valued function $f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ is differentiable. If Jacobian matrix $J_f(x)$ is positive definite for all $x\in\Omega$, prove that $f$ is an injective function on $\Omega$.

I have no way of dealing with it. Is there a theorem to do with it?

Answer (score 2):

Note that, since your domain is convex, you can join any two points $x, y$ by the line segment $c(t) = x + t(y-x)$.
Then
$$f(y)-f(x)=\int_0^1 df(x+t(y-x))(y-x)\, dt$$
Now mulitply this with $y-x$, use the fact that $df$ is positive and the integral linear, to conclude that this is not $=0$ if $y\neq x$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: suppose $x\neq y$ but $f(x)=f(y).\ $ On $\Omega$, define for $0\le t\le 1,\  \gamma (t)=ty+(1-t)x,\ $ which is well-defined because $\Omega$  is convex.

Now, compute $D\langle ((f\circ \gamma)(t)-f(x)), (y-x)\rangle$ and use the Mean Value Theorem and your hypothesis on the Jacobian, to arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: Yes indeed, thanks