# Necessity of a diffeomorphism for the transformation rule of integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, differential-geometry, differential-forms

I have a question regarding the transformation rule of integrals. I will first explain my motivation:
Let $\phi: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable and $f:[\phi(a),\phi(b)] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Then

$ {\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b} \phi'(x)f(\phi(x))dx} $ = $ {\displaystyle \int_{\phi(a)}^{\phi(b)} f(u)du} $,

which follows from Newton-Leibniz formula (As explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution)). Note that it is **not** necessary that $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism. The question is: *Is there an analogous true statement for transforming integrals in higher dimensions?* Normally, the transformation rule requires a diffeomorphic transformation, but I wonder if one could omit this requirement.

Comment: If you track down the motion of $\phi(x)$ as $x$ moves from $a$ to $b$, counting it positively (resp. negatively) if it goes to the right (resp. left), you'll see that most of the motion cancel each other, and as a result, integrating gives the same result as if $\phi$ was injective. This is no more the case in higher dimension since there is more room for $\phi$ to move.

Comment: There are versions of the Change of Variables Theorem in higher dimensions that weaken the hypothesis of a diffeomorphism somewhat (e.g., that the map drops rank on a set of measure 0). You should edit your post to include exactly how far you want to stretch the theorem and on what results you've found.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The higher dimensional situation **is** more complicated than 1D because you have more room and so images of sets are more difficult to characterize (in 1D, the intermediate value theorem tells us the image of an interval is an interval). Another reason why the 1D theorem is so easy to state and prove is that if $a\leq b$, then we *define* $\int_b^a:=-\int_a^b$, so we have built in an order into our notation (the whole purpose being to make the equation $\int_a^b=\int_a^c+\int_c^b$ hold for **all** $a,b,c$, not just those with $a\leq c\leq  b$). This notational trick (together with the chain rule and FTC) allows us to phrase the theorem for $\phi$’s which are not necessarily increasing (which agrees with the comment by @Didier). So, as nice, clean and general the statement/proof are in 1D, I would say it is a fluke.

But still analysts have developed various ways of finessing the change-of-variables formula
\begin{align}
\int_{\phi[\Omega]}f=\int_{\Omega}f\circ\phi\cdot|\det D\phi|.\tag{$*$}
\end{align}

- Usually, $(*)$ is proven when $f\in L^1$ and $\phi$ is a $C^1$ diffeomorphism.
- Using *Sard’s theorem*, one can improve ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4466867/568204)) the result slightly by still requiring $\phi$ to be $C^1$, but allowing $\phi$ to have some critical points, but then we still require that $\phi$ be injective away from the critical set.
- Still assuming $\phi$ is $C^1$, if you now want to drop injectivity of $\phi$ away from the critical set as well, then $(*)$ is no longer true (see the polar coordinate counterexample at the end of the link above). So, you need to take that non-injectivity into account explicitly by counting the cardinality of each preimage $\phi^{-1}(\{y\})$. See Michael E. Taylor’s *Measure Theory and Integration*, Appendix F for the precise statement and proof of such a version.
- Another direction for generalization is the regularity on $\phi$; one can weaken this to $\phi$ being a Lipschitz map. By *Rademacher’s theorem*, Lipschitz maps are a.e differentiable, and since integrals shouldn’t care about measure-zero sets, it would be plausible that one can extend $(*)$ to the case of Lipschitz $\phi$ as well. Another thing one might wonder is whether is is possible to deal with Lipschitz maps $\phi:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}^m$ with perhaps $n\neq m$. Indeed, there are such generalizations; see the *Area and Coarea theorems* in Evans and Gariepy’s *Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions*, Chapter 3 on Area and Coarea formulas.

Despite these generalizations, note that in practice (i.e everyday calculations of volumes, moments of inertia), the first ‘baby version’ (which is already a monster) suffices. The second bullet point is a nice reassurance (but if I’m being honest, I’ve never used the full strength of it… in practical cases one can easily reduce to the previous case even without Sard’s theorem). The third bullet point I’ve never actually had to use, and the final one, I’ve also never had the need for the full strength of the coarea formula with general Lipschitz maps. So my point is that while the generalizations are nice to know, you can probably get away with the basic version for like 95% of “practical stuff”.

Comment: Great answer, although I would have said 99% of the time instead of 95%

Comment: @Didier I was allowing for the possibility of people having a very theoretical interpretation of “practical stuff” :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thinks this pretty much answers my question.