# Is function f injective if its Jacobian matrix is positive definite and domain is non convex?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2292127/360262) has a claim that function $f:\Omega \to \Bbb{R}^n$ is injective if its Jacobian matrix is positive definite and domain is convex.  However the proof heavily depends on the fact that domain is convex, which seems to be a global condition to let $f$ being injective.

In what sense this condition can be generalized to the non-convex domain?

Comment: If the domain is not connected then you can easily create a counterexample.

Comment: Yeah, I know the counterexample can be found evan for one dimensional function, however is there some global condition general than convex makes the statement holds? @copper.hat

Comment: If the domain is open and path connected you could follow the same sort of proof that you referenced.

Comment: Can you elaborate more, consider the star shape region, what we want to prove is value different at every points, I try to use the same idea as Poincare lemma, however there we prove value the same at every point @copper.hat

Comment: All you need is a path-connected set. What is so special about a line segment in the proof you've referenced? (The proof of the Poincaré lemma uses the star-shaped hypothesis to give a specific formula for the primitive of the form so that you can verify that its derivative works out.)

Comment: @Ted Shifrin  , there is an techniquecal difficulty that I can't handle, in convex set $\gamma'(t)$ is contant if we choose straight line , which makes the method works.

Comment: Just mimic the proof in the post above, Assume $\Omega$ is path connected, therefore there is some continuous path from $x$ to $y$, which can be perturbed to be a smooth curve $\gamma :[0,1] \to \Omega$ such that $\gamma(0) = x$, $\gamma(1) = y$.

Therefore 

$$f(y) - f(x) =\int_0^1 \frac{d}{dt}f(\gamma(t)) dt = \int_0^1 \nabla f(\gamma(t))\cdot \dot{\gamma(t)}dt$$ however I can't take $\dot{\gamma}$ into the integral @Ted Shifrin

Comment: Yes, I spoke without thinking carefully. The “integration by parts” term is present for non-constant velocity. Have you looked for a counterexample?

Comment: The use of positive definite for a possibly non-symmetric matrix is also somewhat bothersome to me.

Comment: Yeah, it works for Hessian matrix , which is symmetric

Comment: So you have a proof for gradient fields on a non-convex domain?

Comment: My comment above is wrong.

Comment: no i mean hessian is symmetric